# how can I erase some specific word from a strind and stored it in a temporary variable and send that variable to my query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

Here I wrote three file called "fruit.jsp", "fruitcontroller.java" and "fruitshopDAO.java". In fruit.jsp I am getting some value from browser, the value is like " Fruit Shop - Groth Center". I want to erase the "Groth Center" from my data. and stored it into another variable.And Finally pass that variable to the query. All my files are listed below, Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 /fruit.jsp

    function loadDividendSchemes()
    {
       var scheme = $('#txt_growth_scheme').val(); /* Fruit Shop - Groth Center */

       $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
        $.post("/getFruitShop", {scheme : ""+scheme+""}, function(data)
        {
            var result1 = $.trim(data);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result1);

        }, "text"); 
    }
```

/fruitcontroller.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getFruitShop")
        public void getFruitShop(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
        {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            Gson gson = new Gson();;

            try 
            {
                String requestUrl = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                if(!AdvisorkhojUtils.isValidUrl(requestUrl, "getFruitShop"))
                {
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page-not-found?invalidUrl=" + requestUrl);
                    return;
                }
                String scheme = request.getParameter("scheme"); /* value "Fruit Shop - Groth Center" from the jsp file */

                if(scheme == null || StringHelper.isEmpty(scheme)){scheme = "fruit shop - Growth";}

                scheme = scheme.trim();

                List<String> schemeList = mutualFundPerformanceDAO.getFruitShop(scheme); /* send scheme = "Fruit Shop - Groth Center" to fruitshopDAO.java  */

                response.setContentType("application/json");
                writer.println(gson.toJson(schemeList));
                writer.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

/fruitshopDAO.java

```
 public List<String> getFruitShop(String scheme) 
        {
            Session session = null;
            Query query = null;
            List<String> list = null;

                    /* How can I erase "Groth Center" from scheme and stored remaining string into a new variable called "findshop" and send it to below query */
        /* I want something like "findshop = Fruit Shop -" */   
            try
            {
                session = HibernateUtils.getAdvisorkhojAmfiSession();
                session.getTransaction().begin();

                query = session.createSQLQuery( "from scheme_mapping where fruitshop like 'findshop%'");
                query.setMaxResults(25);
                list = query.list();

                session.getTransaction().commit();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return list;
      }
    }
```

Comment: scheme .substring(0,scheme.indexOf("-") )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you need.

```
String findShop = scheme.substring(0, scheme.indexOf("-"));
```

Further pass it into the query as :

```
"from scheme_mapping where fruitshop like :findShop").setParameter("findShop", findShop+"%");
```